# httpd start fails and shows up error

Tags: systemd, configuration, apache-httpd

I installed Apache through `yum install httpd` in Fedora.  When I try to start the service it shows the following error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable httpd.service 
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service' 

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start httpd.service 
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.



[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status httpd.service 
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server 

   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled) 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2014-05-17 21:19:25 IST; 1h 13min ago 
  Process: 2622 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful-stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 

  Process: 2620 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 


May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Se... 
May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain httpd[2620]: httpd: Syntax error on lin... 
May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process... 
May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain httpd[2622]: httpd: Syntax error on lin... 
May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control proc... 
May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache ... 
May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered ... 
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: You seriously show us that error message but not the output of `systemctl status httpd.service`...?

Comment: i have edited the post now above.. please check the httpd status i mentioned .. thanku

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to give us the useless `May 17 21:19:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]:` part on each line but truncate the real information afterwards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there is a syntax error in Apache's configuration file.

Comment: i reinstalled apache. but the same error again.. yeah that date part cuts off the actual error log info.i am helpless.. what can i do now?

Comment: @harzyne But this problem should not exist for `journalctl -xn`. And as `systemctl status httpd.service` should have told you: `systemctl -l status httpd.service` gives you the complete lines.

Comment: @haryzne You can widen the terminal before running `systemctl status httpd.service`.  This will cause the output to be less truncated.

Comment: @harzyne Uninstalling packages doesn't necessarily remove their config files, so a syntax error would persist across reinstallation.

Comment: Use the command `httpd configtest` to check the config.